# Is It Possible To Show One More Views In Homepage

Tags: views, nodes

I have created some Views to show in Home page. I have successfully installed one View in my homepage but i really can't understand is it possible to show one more Views in Homepage. If it possible then please take a time to describe it.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 7, you should create a "block" display for the views you want to show, by selecting "Add" in the view config page.

[image]

When you save the view block, the corresponding blocks will show up in the `/admin/structure/block` administration page and you can add it to any page you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you have it set up as a Page display, then no, not really -- those are designed to show one view at a time, though you can probably install [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view/) and then add one of those to the footer if you're set on that.

However, the simpler route is to just create a Block from that view and add it to pages that way. Click the Add button near the word "Displays" when editing a view. Then you can drag and drop them in admin/structure/block.

To set it only on the home page, in admin/structure/block, click Configure next to the Views block in question. Under Pages at the bottom, click "Only the listed pages" and put "" in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use panels you setup your panel structure and then add the views this give you the layout you want with minimal effort.